# DropDownList values to DataType.Date Model (ASP.NET MVC 4)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model, html-select

For a while now I have tried to work my head around this small issue. Research done only confused me more and some attempts did not work.

So, if you think you can help me ease my pain, I will appreciate it greatly!

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC4 Mobile applications, I am creating a simple registration page with only a few details, one of them is Date of Birth, which I would prefer to be a set of dropdownlist instead of datepicker (as it is for mobiles I want it to be simple :) ).

Here is the bit of code that populates my dropdownlists in my View page:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <legend>D.O.B</legend>
            @Html.DropDownList("Day", Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString()}), "Day")
            @Html.DropDownList("Month", Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i)}), "Month")
            @Html.DropDownList("Year", Enumerable.Range(1900, 114).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString()}), "Year")
</fieldset>
```

I wanna be able to "map" the values from here to my Register model which right now it looks like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

Any help or straight answer will be greatly appreciate it. If you need more info please feel free to ask. Thank you very much.

Regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of a DateTime in your model you can have three ints

```
        public int Day { get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
```

and in your view you would do

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Day, Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString()}), "Day")
        @Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Month, Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i)}), "Month")
        @Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Year,  Enumerable.Range(1900, 114).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString()}), "Year")
```

Once you are in the controller you can make a datetime out of these 3 ints and store them in the database

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

If you need more guidance on Forms and Models with MVC I suggest you go through this ASP.NET MVC guide - it is pretty comprehensive:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-helpers,-forms-and-validation

Comment: This may work, but then I'm confused as to how to add all three values in the database in the format DD/MM/YYYY :S Hmm may have to do a bit more of research on this. Thank you though :)

Comment: once you get to your controller method you can create a date out of these three integers and store it as a datetime in your database.. but when displaying it in a view you can do it anyway you like in a form